Correlation with impulse function
Let $\delta$ be the impulse signal for two variables, that is, $\delta(i, j) = 1$ if $i=j=0$, otherwise $\delta(i,j) = 0$. The text I am reading states that, given an image (function) $f$, the correlation $f \oplus \delta$ evaluates to the reflected version of $f$. I am not sure whether I understand this.
If we compute
$$
(f \oplus \delta) (i, j) = \sum_{k, l} f(i + k, j + l) \delta(k, l) = f(i, j),
$$
which is the same as our original image $f$. What did I do wrong?

Do you mean convolution?  That's the * usually represents.  The formula for convolution has a minus sign however.

I'm not sure if you're referring to a convolution, or a correlation. (I can't find a convenient definition of the latter.) However, if we define the convolution by
$$
(a \ast b)(i,j) := \sum_{k,\ell} a(k,\ell) b(i-k,j-\ell)
$$
then $(f \ast \delta)(i,j) = f(-i,-j)$.

@Paul I mean correlation.  In my text, they use this symbol $\oplus$.

@PrincessEev The summation in the post is the definition my text is using (if we insert $f$ and $\delta$).
